# Unable to mint token, please someone to help

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

here is my code below, i am trying to mint token and its not working, please someone should help me

```
require('dotenv').config();

const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js'); const splToken = require('@solana/spl-token');

// Add the Token Program ID here const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA");

async function main() {   const privateKeyString = process.env['PRIVATE_KEY'];   const privateKeyBytes = privateKeyString.split(',').map(Number);

  const walletKeyPair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(privateKeyBytes));

  const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection("https://nd-519-484-423.p2pify.com/8a1f983c912a2b45e455ed96c59cfee2", { wsEndpoint: "wss://ws-nd-519-484-423.p2pify.com/8a1f983c912a2b45e455ed96c59cfee2" });

  try {
    let balance = await connection.getBalance(walletKeyPair.publicKey);
    console.log(balance / solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
   } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching balance:', error.message);   }

  try {
    const mint = await splToken.createMint(
      connection,
      walletKeyPair,
      walletKeyPair.publicKey,
      null,
      9,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    );
    
    console.log('Mint address:', mint.toBase58());
  
    // Create an associated token account
    const associatedTokenAccount = await splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      walletKeyPair,
      walletKeyPair.publicKey,
      mint,
    );

    console.log('Token Account address:', associatedTokenAccount.toBase58()); 

    // Log associatedTokenAccount details
    console.log('Associated Token Account:', associatedTokenAccount);

    // Mint to the associated token account
    const mintAmount = 1000000000000000;
    const instructions = await splToken.createMintToInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      mint,
      associatedTokenAccount,
      walletKeyPair.publicKey,
      [],
      mintAmount,
    );

    const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(...instructions);

    // Sign and send the transaction
    const signature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [walletKeyPair],
      { commitment: 'singleGossip', preflightCommitment: 'singleGossip' }
    );

    console.log('Transaction Signature:', signature);

    console.log('Minting successful!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error minting tokens:', error);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Without knowing the error, we don't have any idea where to start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't provide information about the error, just the user's code with no indication of the problem or solutions attempted.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the splToken.mintTo it's much more directe and don't need to pass an instrcution!

Last time i check 1 month or 2months ago solana/web3.js use VersionedTransaction

```
const blockHash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;

const msg = new solanaWeb3.TransactionMessage({
  instructions: ['instrcutions'],
  payerKey: payer.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: blockHash
 }).compileToLegacyMessage();

const vtx = new solanaWeb3.VersionedTransaction(msg);

vtx.sign(['all the signers'])

const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(vtx);
```

Comment: i already figured it out

Comment: Your answer doesn't work, please specify where to use splToken.mintTo in the code example

Comment: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token

instead of using splToken.createMintToInstruction use splToken.mintTo